# How to access country names via CultureInfo.GetCultures

Tags: c#, .net

I want to access countries, states and cites name through c# code. Till now i was successfully accessed countries name through CulturalInfo class my code for countries name :

```
    public string[] Get()
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> CountryNameDictonary = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        foreach (System.Globalization.CultureInfo ci in System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultures(System.Globalization.CultureTypes.SpecificCultures))
        {
            System.Globalization.RegionInfo ri = new System.Globalization.RegionInfo(ci.Name);
            if (!CountryNameDictonary.ContainsKey(ri.EnglishName))
            {
                CountryNameDictonary.Add(ri.EnglishName, ri.TwoLetterISORegionName);
            }
        }

        var OrderedNames = CountryNameDictonary.OrderBy(p => p.Key);

        Dictionary<string, string> Countries = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> val in OrderedNames)
        {
            Countries.Add(val.Key, val.Value);
        }

        return Countries.Keys.ToArray();
    }
```

Now i am stucked and did`nt get how to access the states and cites name.I want the list of states and cities of each selected country on the easiest way to do it without going back to edit the data source (database or XML).How can i do this, please help?

Comment: .NET is a development framework, not a geographical directory... You will have to implement this yourself!

Comment: I'll have to disappoint you, but you will never get any further this way to get the cities and states. Mainly because they aren't there. To get your countries, cities and states. I suggest building your source an other way.

Comment: I'll have to disappoint you, but you will never get any further this way to get the cities and states. Mainly because they aren't there. To get your countries, cities and states. I suggest building your source an other way (database, xml file, ... ).

Comment: There's no built in list of cities in .NET.  What do you mean by "without going back to edit the data source?"  You don't have to edit a source to read from it, but you do have to have a data source to read from...

Comment: You say about going back to edit "the data source" but your question makes no other reference to it?

Comment: ok thanks but it will be great if you guys guid me the way to do this

Comment: any better idea or any other guidence

Comment: Guide you the way to do what?  You need to google a list of cities, or build a list of your own.

Comment: The collection of states and Cities you need to do manually, need to keep some where in Database for particular country.

Comment: @TomRider,
The collection of states and Cities you need to do manually, need to keep some where in Database for particular country.

Answer (score 0):

On this US government Website you can get a list of cities and other geographical features: http://earth-info.nga.mil/gns/html/namefiles.htm.

You can extract the data out of the files and populate your own database with them and then query it from your application.

You cannot do it from `CultureInfo` nor anything from the .NET framework as it doesn't provide such thing.